# Flask: why is request.args not taking in second parameter?

Tags: python, flask, cs50

greet.html, index.html and layout.html is all inside templates folder. Both template folder and app.py is inside hello folder. I step inside hello folder to run flask. when a word is entered into form, everything is displayed correctly. But when nothing is entered, it only shows "hello, ". it is not replaced by the "world" as specified in app.py?
layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="intial-scale=1,width=device-width">
        <title>hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="/greet" method="get">
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Greet</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

greet.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

    hello, {{ name }}

{% endblock %}
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/greet")
def greet():
    name = request.args.get("name","world")
    return render_template("greet.html",name=name)
```

Comment: The folder needs to be called `templates`, not `template`.

Comment: @larsks thanks! now that i run into another issue - when nothing is entered into the form. it will give "hello, " instead of "hello, world". which makes me confuse on what is causing the issue?

Comment: `request.args.get(“name”,”world”)` will use “world” as a default value if there is no value for name in args. You do have a value for name in args however and it will be an empty string if the field was left blank on the form. Try `request.args.get(“name”) or “world”` instead.

Comment: but in the case where when it is request.form.get, it does get the default value when none is entered. If the below line changes to request.args.get("name",world"), then nothing will show up when no input is entered. In both case, name is in the dictionary? What may cause the difference then? @app.route("/") def index(): if "name" in request.args: return request.form.get("name", "world") return render_template("index.html")